windows 11 error The Secure Boot update failed
for some reason this error is constantly thrown and logged in the Windows Event Viewer:
The Secure Boot update failed to update a Secure Boot variable with error Secure Boot is not enabled on this machine.. For more information, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2169931
However, when I restart the machine and go into the BIOS settings - the Secure Boot is turned ON. Any clue??
Why the error happens if the Secure Boot is set to ON in BIOS settings?
PC specs are as follows:

OS: Windows 11 (licensed)
CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900KS, Socket 1700 LGA (0x1)
Chipset
Northbridge: Intel Alder Lake rev. 02
Southbridge: Intel Z690 rev. 11
Bus Specification: PCI-Express 5.0 (32.0 GT/s)
Graphic Interface: PCI-Express
Memory Type: DDR5
Memory Size: 32 GBytes
Channels: 4 x 32-bit
Memory Frequency: 3200.0 MHz (1:32)
Memory Max Frequency: 3200.0 MHz
CAS# latency (CL): 32.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD): 39
RAS# Precharge (tRP): 39
Cycle Time (tRAS): 80
Bank Cycle Time (tRC): 119
Row Refresh Cycle Time (tRFC): 510
Command Rate (CR): 2T
Uncore Frequency: 3600.0 MHz
Memory Controller Frequency: 1600.0 MHz
Host Bridge: 0x4660
Motherboard:
manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.
product: Z690 AORUS MASTER

some error details from the event log:


System

Provider

[ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-TPM-WMI     [ Guid]
{7d5387b0-cbe0-11da-a94d-0800200c9a66}
EventID 1796
Version 0
Level 2
Task 0
Opcode 0
Keywords 0x8000000000000000

TimeCreated

[ SystemTime]  2024-05-27T07:08:36.3761094Z
EventRecordID 77810
Correlation

Execution

[ ProcessID]  3312     [ ThreadID]  15248
Channel System
Computer DESKTOP-NSFJJ4C

Security

[ UserID]  S-1-5-18

EventData
HResult -2147020471




Do you have KB5034440 installed? Microsoft over the last 12 months has spent preparing to update and revoke a certificate used by Secure Boot. One of the things that has happened is that Microsoft has updated the Secure Boot DBX. This also requires WinRE to be updated. This error is likely linked to this update. We will need more information to completely diagnose your issue. What’s the event id of the error, that information, isn’t contained in your question

@Ramhound that update is not installed on my PC. I can't find it in the history

Has it failed to install? What size is your WinRE? Check if there are any firmware updates: Windows Settings > Windows Update > Additional Settings > Optional updates

Verify you have this update

the KB5034440 update is not listed in the optional updates nor in the installed updates

the KB5012170 is also not listed neither in the installed updates list nor in the optional updates. It looks like I have no way to get those updates at all

Why don’t you? Wasn’t tracking a WU issue.

Windows updates were regularly installed, I was notified about that and was restarting my PC to complete the updates installation. I had no idea that some updates are not applied for some reason

@Ramhound probably for the Windows 11 those updates are not mandatory? Or they are not listed as regular updates for some reason? This situation looks really weird. Why I'm missing those updates on my PC and there is no way to install the updates?

One requires the manual intervention of expanding the size of the WinRE partition the other one should have been installed automatically. You said you have no way to get those updates, I asked, why you believe that.

This damn thing always make green screens and reboots my computer every 10 minutes.

the Secure Boot mode was Enabled and forced to the Active state by following steps from this amazing video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eC9gT8mDPY
many thanks to the author of that short youtube tutorial!
The steps are as follows:

Enter BIOS by pressing the DEL keyboard key during the initial boot of the device.
navigate to the BOOT section in the BIOS management GUI
make sure, that the CSM Support is disabled, if not - change it to DISABLED!
Secure Boot Mode change to Custom
Secure Boot Mode change to Standart
Install factory defaults - click YES
Reset Without Saving - NO
Secure Boot - set to ENABLED if it's not enabled yet
Secure Boot Mode - make sure that the STANDART option is selected

save & exit the BIOS tool, the restart procedure of your PC should start automatically.
Voila! It works! Now, the Secure Boot State is ON


the update KB5034440 https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5034440 doesn't even exist

I am aware that KB5034440 is not listed in the Windows Update Catalog.  Microsoft has chosen not to publish it there. However, it most certainly does exist. and likely very relevant. because of this vulnerability. Verify WinRE was updated
